# Как побороть ошибку «Wrong response from the webhook: 404 Not Found»?

Tags: telegram-bot, webhook

Создал домен для бота, получил ssl-сертификат, проверил его на подлинность. Начал подключать вебхук и тут столкнулся с проблемой - сам вебхук подключил ({"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook is already set"}), написал код для бота и он не работает. Начал винить сначала в этом домен и ssl-сертификат, но потом понял, что они не причем. Оказывается у меня по запросу [https://api.telegram.org/bot[BOT_TOKEN]/getWebhookInfo](https://api.telegram.org/bot%5BBOT_TOKEN%5D/getWebhookInfo) приходит следующая ошибка - "last_error_message":"Wrong response from the webhook: 404 Not Found". Не могу понять, как с ней бороться?

Comment: setWebhook вообще делали?

Comment: @MyZik да, конечно. Делал по этой ссылке - https://api.telegram.org/bot[BOT_TOKEN]/setWebhook?url=https://incrediblebot.ru/bot.php

Comment: И какой ответ от сервера получили?

Comment: И что приходит от getMe?

Comment: @MyZik починил ошибку 404, но возникла другая, под номером 500 Internal Server Error. От запроса getMe пришло следующее {"ok":true,"result":{"id":[BOT_ID],"is_bot":true,"first_name":"[BOT_NAME]","username":"[BOT_USERNAME]","can_join_groups":true,"can_read_all_group_messages":false,"supports_inline_queries":false}}

Comment: Тут уже смотрите логи сервера, бота, причина может быть где угодно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему: оказывается нужно было поместить файл с кодом для бота на сервер, ибо только туда будет идти запрос и там он будет обрабатываться

Убедитесь, что в доменном имени вы указываете название файла с исполняемым кодом, а не какое либо другое название (Например: исполняемый код называется bot.php, следовательно доменное имя будет выглядеть так - example.com/bot.php)

Вроде бы банально, но нигде об этом не написано, когда начинаешь создавать бота с нуля
Надеюсь все более менее понятно объяснил